# Can you change your hunter name?

Tags: monster-hunter-3-ultimate

Somewhat self-explanatory, really. I've had my current hunter name for awhile, chose it mostly on a whim because I thought I'd be hunting solo for the most part. Now that I will be hunting online, I want to change my name, but I don't know where to do this or whether it is even possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No. You cannot change your character name.** Your only option to have a different character name is to start a new character.

In Tri, you could not change your character name either, but you could use a different login ID for the online component which was at least something. In Ultimate, that is no longer applicable. Your character is stuck with the name you gave them. There are many sources on [google](https://www.google.ca/search?q=monster+hunter+3+ultimate+name+change) and even [reviews](http://nintendodude.com/monster-hunter-3-ultimate-wii-u-review/) testifying to this fact.